# Is there a more precise way to play F natural on a D pennywhistle?

Tags: technique, fingering, penny-whistle

I am using a pennywhistle in the key of D major. I was wondering if there is an easy way to make the F# (the third hole from the end) an F natural (between the third and second holes from the end). I am aware that you can theoretically half-cover the lower hole, but this is hard to do precisely in faster passages, and can easily sound messy. Is there a more precise way to finger this?

Comment: On the recorder (which has an extra hole for the C) you get the F♮ by covering all holes except the third. Analogously I'd suspect on the tin whistle you can get something F-like by covering all except the second hole, but I haven't one to test how usable this is. You may need to partially cover the second hole anyway to get the tone low enough.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Thank you, good ideas. I'll have to do some testing with my guitar tuner to see how precise it is :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really.  You can always mess around and see if you find anything, but you're not going to find anything simpler than the main fingering.  Pennywhistle involves a ton of half-holing, you'd better just get used to it.